# How can i change JSON variable to 3 variable with same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I trying to change 'image' variable to 3 variable 'small','medium','big' with same value.

**OLD JSON :**

```
[ 
  {
  "name": "nameimage1",
  "Images": [ {"image":"1.jpg"}, {"image":"2.jpg"}, {"image":"3.jpg"} ]
  },
  {
  "name": "nameimage2",
  "Images": [ {"image":"4.jpg"}, {"image":"5.jpg"}, {"image":"6.jpg"} ]
  }
]
```

**And I want to change JSON like this :**

```
[ 
  {
  "name": "nameimage1",
  "Images": [ {"small":"1.jpg","medium":"1.jpg","big":"1.jpg"}, 
              {"small":"2.jpg","medium":"2.jpg","big":"2.jpg"}, 
              {"small":"3.jpg","medium":"3.jpg","big":"3.jpg"} ]
  },
  {
  "name": "nameimage2",
  "Images": [ {"small":"4.jpg","medium":"4.jpg","big":"4.jpg"}, 
              {"small":"5.jpg","medium":"5.jpg","big":"5.jpg"}, 
              {"small":"6.jpg","medium":"6.jpg","big":"6.jpg"} ]
  }
]
```

**I'm trying to use for loop like this :**

```
function getrealJSON() {
    fetch('text/realgallery.json').then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            var gallery = [];
            var album = {};
            var albums = [];
            var pic = {};
            for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                // console.log(data[a].Images)
                console.log(data[a].name)
                for (let i = 0; i < data[a].Images.length; i++) {
       pic['big'] = pic['medium'] = pic['small'] = data[a].Images[i];
                    album['Images'] = pic;
                    albums.push(album);
                }
            }
            console.log(albums);
```

But It's not work because It's only show last source of image

My Result : [please see my result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FymwQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the objects with `Images` property and map new objects.

```js
var data = [{ name: "nameimage1", Images: [{ image: "1.jpg" }, { image: "2.jpg" }, { image: "3.jpg" }] }, { name: "nameimage2", Images: [{ image: "4.jpg" }, { image: "5.jpg" }, { image: "6.jpg" }] }];

data = data.map(o => Object.assign(
    {},
    o,
    { Images: o.Images.map(({ image }) => ({ small: image, medium: image, big: image })) }
));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I got it : )

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop to loop through an JSON object. An JSON object does not work the same way as an array, so you can't loop through it with OBJECT_NAME[i].

You could do something like this:

```
Object.keys(OBJECT_NAME).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(OBJECT_NAME[key]);
});
```

You could also use nested foreach loop for multidimensional objects. I don't know if this is the best practise, but it is a solution.

Comment: Thanks you very much,Now I got it with Nina Scholz's answer.